# Dart equivalent syntax

Tags: dart, operators

> Dart Language

What is the equivalent operator for the "as" operator in type checking during runtime?

```
var foo = new Teacher();
var bar = new Student();
like (foo as Teacher);
```

Output

> Instance ofTteacher

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent operator is "is"
(foo is Teacher) should return true or false accordingly if foo is of type Teacher or otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Key word `as` is used for type conversion.

If you want to check foo is `Teacher` or not:

```
print(foo is Teacher);
print(bar is Student);
```

If you just want to get Type of foo:

```
final fooType = foo.runtimeType;
final barType = bar.runtimeType;
print(fooType == barType);
```

Both `fooType` and `barType` is instance of `Type`.

Comment: Do not use .runtimeType.  It might be a subclass.  It's meant only for diagnostic messages and internal use.